# Using ios_base::register_callback() and ios_base::event to detect stream closing

Tags: c++, callback, stream

I have an API that returns a `unique_ptr<ofstream>` to the API user. I would like to know when the user is finished with this stream so I can take further action on the file they just wrote to. It's imperative that the file be closed because a partition is about to be remounted.

It might be the wrong solution to this problem, but right before I return the stream I register a callback with [register_callback()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/register_callback):

```
std::unique_ptr<std::ofstream> os(new std::ofstream(name, std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::trunc | std::ofstream::binary));
os->register_callback(done_callback, 0);
return os;
```

The callback is defined elsewhere:

```
void done_callback(std::ios_base::event evt, std::ios_base& str, int idx)
{
    // Do something when the file closes ... and only then.
}
```

Now, [ios_base::event](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/event) tells the callback a little about what just happened. One event is [erase_event](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/event), and one of the triggers of this event is the destruction of the stream object. This would work for me. I'm concerned though about the other condition that triggers the callback - [copyfmt()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/copyfmt).

- Should I worry about about this or just trust that no one will cause
  [copyfmt()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/copyfmt) to be called?
- Is there a better way to accomplish my
  goal?

Here is source I used to test this (complete, cut/paste), followed by the output of that program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <memory>

void done_callback(std::ios_base::event evt, std::ios_base& str, int idx)
{
    std::cout << "Some sort of stream event occurred. Event: " << evt << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::cout << "Opening the stream." << std::endl;
    std::unique_ptr<std::ofstream> os(new std::ofstream("test", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::trunc | std::ofstream::binary));
    std::cout << "Stream is open." << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Registering callback." << std::endl;
    os->register_callback(done_callback, 0);

    std::cout << "Writing to stream." << std::endl;
    *(os.get()) << "Hello!\n";
    std::cout << "Done writing." << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Flushing stream." << std::endl;
    os->flush();
    std::cout << "Done flushing." << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Writing to stream." << std::endl;
    *(os.get()) << "Hello!\n";
    std::cout << "Done writing." << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Closing the stream..." << std::endl;
    os->close();
    std::cout << "Stream is closed." << std::endl;
}
```

The output:

```
Opening the stream.
Stream is open.
Registering callback.
Writing to stream.
Done writing.
Flushing stream.
Done flushing.
Writing to stream.
Done writing.
Closing the stream...
Stream is closed.
Some sort of stream event occurred. Event: 0
```

Comment: Callbacks are built right into the stream so I see no better alternative. Also, if you can protect against that corner case (however rare it may be) I'd say go for it.

Comment: Any ideas on how to protect against it?

Comment: You mean `copyfmt()`? When the user calls that function state is being transferred from one stream to another. Check if the `event` flag equals `copyfmt_event` and perform any operations as needed.

Comment: I don't think this is really needed unless you're working with pointer storage (`pword`s) that you need to release or copy over.

Comment: I don't think checking for `copyfmt_event` will work to detect that situation, since the callback is used both before and after `copyfmt()`, and there doesn't appear to be a way to tell the difference between the destructor and the "before copy of members" call triggered by `copyfmt()`.

Comment: `erase_event` handles the destruction and `copyfmt_event` handles the copy. There's no need to distinguish what stage you're on.

Comment: But after the copy, that means someone might very, very soon try to open it again. That might cause my remount operation to fail if they beat me to it. Unlikely, but something to guard against if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the `ios::event` parameter to `erase_event` to detect stream destruction. To guard against copying the `erase_event` handler, you could teach it to neuter itself upon `copyfmt_event`.

However, this isn't a good way to manage files. (And anything about safe file management counts double for partitions.) The `fstream` object isn't what holds the file open, the `filebuf` is. Standard stream objects only handle formatting; stream *buffer* objects handle I/O.

Fortunately, `streambuf` has a [virtual destructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/~basic_streambuf), so you can derive from `std::filebuf` and add some functionality there. Unfortunately, a destructor should always be fail-safe, so it isn't a very good place to mount a filesystem. You should only enqueue the mount operation in the application's to-do list.